# Groovy Generics failure

Tags: java, generics, groovy

Besides groovy is way more dynamic then java...

Why is this a compile time error in groovy (unexpected token `<`):

```
interface A {
     <T> T getByClass(Class<T> clazz)
}
```

How do I write this the groovy way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Groovy parser does not handle [method signatures beginning with Generic information](https://user.groovy.codehaus.narkive.com/G7kxM22B/groovy-generic-interface-declaration-incompatibility#post2)...

It parses if you add the public modifier:

```
interface A {
  public <T> T getByClass( Class<T> clazz )
}
```

Though I don't believe you'll gain any type checking at compile time for adding this annotation

Comment: Thanks. That works. I just want to understand a groovy (ast transforming) dependency injection system from [telluriumsource](http://code.google.com/p/aost/source/browse/branches/trunk-0.8.0/injector/src/?r=5219#src%2Fmain%2Fgroovy%2Forg%2Ftelluriumsource). Just now its copy-paste-debug, later on I will change it to my needs.