# Implementing Generic Interface in Groovy

Tags: generics, groovy

**Edit:** stripped down to the main issue.

I am trying to implement Springs `CrudRepository<T, ID>` in a Groovy class, which fails to compile with:

> Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. The class [..] must be declared abstract or the method '**java.lang.Object save(java.lang.Object)**' must be implemented.

These errors affect the methods with `<S extends T>` signature only. There is a [Groovy bug filed for issues with Generics](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4415), but it should be resolved! I kept with [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395527/groovy-generics-failure) and added the modifiers, but still cannot compile.

## Example

The following code won't compile in IntelliJ Groovy console on my machine using javac, Eclipse compiler or Groovy-Eclipse.

```
class Account { int id }

interface Repo<T, ID> {
    public T get(ID id)
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity)
}

class AccountRepo implements Repo<Account, Long> {

    @Override
    Account get(Long aLong) {
        return null
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Account> S save(S entity) {
        return null
    }
}
```

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
ideaGroovyConsole.groovy: 9: Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. The class 'AccountRepo' must be declared abstract or the method 'java.lang.Object save(java.lang.Object)' must be implemented.
 @ line 9, column 1.
   class AccountRepo implements Repo<Account, Long> {
   ^

1 error
```

Just for the record, I am using Groovy 2.5.4.

Comment: I tried your code and I don't get any compilation errors

Comment: @Dónal thanks for trying. In case of version problems I added information of my setup and further explained what my IDE does.

Comment: Could you please let us know, what's the version of the Intellij you are using?

Comment: @Kootli sure, here we go.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found out to solve it was to write a Java Adapter class, that bridges the methods with Generics in their signature:

```java
public abstract class RepositoryGenericsAdapter<T extends Identifiable, ID> implements CrudRepository<T, ID> {

    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
        // getId() provided via Identifiable interface
        if (entity.getId() == null) {
            create(entity);
        } else {
            update(entity);
        }

        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {
        entities.forEach(this::save);
        return entities;
    }

    // These operations accept generic class type <T> instead of <S extends T>:

    protected abstract void update(T entity);

    protected abstract void create(T entity);
}
```

While the interface is left unchanged, the Groovy implementation extends the Adapter and implements the abstract methods:

```groovy
class AccountRepo extends RepositoryGenericsAdapter<Account, Long>
        implements Repo<Account, Long> {

    @Override
    Account get(Long aLong) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Account create(Account entity) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Account update(Account entity) {
        // ...
    }
}
```